# Chrome 53 Auto-reload generated CSS option not available (Windows 7)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

How can I get chrome to auto-reload generated css?

I've seen lots of sites advising me to check the "Auto-reload generated CSS" checkbox in dev tools settings, eg [Chrome's "Auto-Reload Generated CSS" not reloading page when SASS recompiles CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886807/chromes-auto-reload-generated-css-not-reloading-page-when-sass-recompiles-css).

But I do not see that option there, my options page has the option to enable CSS source maps, but there is no option for "Auto-reload generated CSS"

(Unfortunately, my work internet proxy prevents upload of images, so i can't upload an image)

Has this option been removed from chrome dev tools? Or is there some hidden config setting I need to change?

I'm using chrome version 53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit) on Windows 7 SP1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://crbug.com/642802:

> When you add a folder to the workspace and establish mapping, this happens automatically now.

See [Set Up Persistence with DevTools Workspaces](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow):

[image: WS]

In case you've already mapped your local folder to your workspace, but the browser is still serving the network folder contents to automatically stage persistent changes in the browser, map local files in the folder to a URL:

[image: mapping]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. <br> I have already done that, but the css files are not reloading

Comment: The problem is happening because the assets are copied to another directory which is used host the web app.

ie files are edited in src directory, then compiled and copied to webserver directory.

Because the compiled css files are not in the same location as the source files, chrome doesn't know how to resolve them.
I guess that's an issue for another question